# How to make my jframe scrollable without getting rid of the text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scrollbar, scrollable

So I'm having a bit of a problem with trying to figure out how to add a scrollbar to my Jframe window. I figured out how to do this but when I implemented it all of the components that were supposed to show up in the frame didn't so instead I got a blank frame. How do I make my frame scrollable?

Here if my code for my GUI:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;
public class FirstGUI2 {
private Container pane;
final boolean fill = true;
final boolean weightX = true;
final boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;
public String mon = "";
public String tues = "";
public String wed = "";
public String thu = "";
public String fri = "";
private JTextArea textAreaMon = new JTextArea(mon);
private JTextArea textAreaTue = new JTextArea(tues);
private JTextArea textAreaWed = new JTextArea(wed);
private JTextArea textAreaThu = new JTextArea(thu);
private JTextArea textAreaFri = new JTextArea(fri);
private JTextArea description;

public void addComponents(Container pane) {
    if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    JButton button;
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    button = new JButton("Open File");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    pane.add(button, c);

    textAreaMon = new JTextArea(mon);
    // textAreaMon.append(mon.substring(0));
    textAreaMon.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreaMon.setEditable(false);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    //JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textAreaMon);
    pane.add(textAreaMon, c);

    textAreaTue = new JTextArea(tues);
    textAreaTue.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreaTue.setEditable(false);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    pane.add(textAreaTue, c);

    textAreaWed = new JTextArea(wed);
    textAreaWed.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreaWed.setEditable(false);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 4;
    pane.add(textAreaWed, c);

    textAreaThu = new JTextArea(thu);
    textAreaThu.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreaThu.setEditable(false);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 5;
    pane.add(textAreaThu, c);

    textAreaFri = new JTextArea(fri);
    textAreaFri.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreaFri.setEditable(false);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 6;
    pane.add(textAreaFri, c);

    description = new JTextArea(
            "\n Click the open button in order to select and im"
            + "port your .csv file. Your scehdule and times will be displayed in the schedule below.\n");
    description.setEditable(false);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;

    pane.add(description, c);

    // attaching the file opener to the open file button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            new InterfacePanel();
            //textAreaMon.setText(mon);
            makeGUI();
        }
    });
}

// creates the frame and showing the GUI to the user
public static void makeGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final Exam Scheduler");
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    FirstGUI2 add = new FirstGUI2();

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    add.addComponents(frame.getContentPane());
    frame.setContentPane(pane);

    add.printToGUI();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void printToGUI() {
    // JText Fields
    mon = "Monday: \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t Group Exam 1 \n 10:15-12:15:\t Group Exam 2 \n 12:45 - 2:45:\t";
//  while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time1.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time1.size(); i++) {
            mon += ArrayListsForClasses.time1.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time1.get(i).displayCourse());
            mon += ", ";
        }
    //}
    mon += "\n 3:00 - 5:00:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time2.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time2.size(); i++) {
            mon += ArrayListsForClasses.time2.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time2.get(i).displayCourse());
            mon += ", ";
        }
    //}
    mon += "\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t Group Exam 3 \n 7:45 - 9:45:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time3.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time3.size(); i++) {
            mon += ArrayListsForClasses.time3.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time3.get(i).displayCourse());
            mon += ", ";
        }
    //}
    mon += "\n \n";
    textAreaMon.setText(mon);

    // textAreaTues
    tues = "Tuesday: \n \n 8:00 - 10:00: \t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time4.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time4.size(); i++) {
            tues += ArrayListsForClasses.time4.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time4.get(i).displayCourse());
            tues += ", ";
        }
    //}
    tues += "\n 10:15 - 12:15:\t Group Exam 4 \n 12:45 - 2:45:\t ";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time5.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time5.size(); i++) {
            tues += ArrayListsForClasses.time5.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time5.get(i).displayCourse());
            tues += ", ";
        }
    //}
    tues += "\n 3:00 - 5:00:\t ";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time6.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time6.size(); i++) {
            tues += ArrayListsForClasses.time6.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time6.get(i).displayCourse());
            tues += ", ";
        }
    //}
    tues += "\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t ";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time7.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time7.size(); i++) {
            tues += ArrayListsForClasses.time7.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time7.get(i).displayCourse());
            tues += ", ";
        }
    //}
    tues += "\n 7:45 - 9:45:\t ";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time8.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time8.size(); i++) {
            tues += ArrayListsForClasses.time8.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time8.get(i).displayCourse());
            tues += ", ";
        }
    //}
    tues += "\n \n";
    textAreaTue.setText(tues);

    // TextAreaWed
    wed = "Wednesday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time9.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time9.size(); i++) {
            wed += ArrayListsForClasses.time9.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time9.get(i).displayCourse());
            wed += ", ";
        }
    //}
    wed += "\n 10:15-12:15:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time10.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time10.size(); i++) {
            wed += ArrayListsForClasses.time10.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time10.get(i).displayCourse());
            wed += ", ";
        }
    //}
    wed += "\n 12:45 - 2:45 :\t Group Exam 5 \n 3:00 - 5:00:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time11.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time11.size(); i++) {
            wed += ArrayListsForClasses.time11.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time11.get(i).displayCourse());
            wed += ", ";
        }
    //}
    wed += "\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time12.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time12.size(); i++) {
            wed += ArrayListsForClasses.time12.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time12.get(i).displayCourse());
            wed += ", ";
        }
    //}
    wed += "\n 7:45 - 9:45:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time13.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time13.size(); i++) {
            wed += ArrayListsForClasses.time13.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time13.get(i).displayCourse());
            wed += ", ";
        }
    //}
    wed += "\n \n";
    textAreaWed.setText(wed);
    // TextAreaThurs
    thu = "Thursday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time14.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time14.size(); i++) {
            thu += ArrayListsForClasses.time14.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time14.get(i).displayCourse());
            thu += ", ";
        }
    //}
    thu += "\n 10:15-12:15 :\t Group Exam 6 \n 12:45 - 2:45:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time15.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time15.size()-1; i++) {
            thu += ArrayListsForClasses.time15.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time15.get(i).displayCourse());
            thu += ", ";
        }
    //}
    thu += "\n 3:00 - 5:00:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time16.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time16.size(); i++) {
            thu += ArrayListsForClasses.time16.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time16.get(i).displayCourse());
            thu += ", ";
        }
    //}
    thu += "\n 5:30 - 7:30:\t Group Exam 7 \n 7:45 - 9:45:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time17.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time17.size(); i++) {
            thu += ArrayListsForClasses.time17.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time17.get(i).displayCourse());
            thu += ", ";
        }
    //}
    thu += "\n \n";
    textAreaThu.setText(thu);

    // TextAreaFri
    fri = "Friday \n \n 8:00 - 10:00:\t Group Exam 8 \n 10:15-12:15:\t";
    //while (!ArrayListsForClasses.time18.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayListsForClasses.time18.size(); i++) {
            fri += ArrayListsForClasses.time18.get(i).displayCourse();
            System.out.println("Added to string for GUI: " + ArrayListsForClasses.time18.get(i).displayCourse());
            fri += ", ";
        }
    //}
    fri += "\n 12:45 - 2:45:\t Group Exam 9";
    fri += "\n \n";
    textAreaFri.setText(fri);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            makeGUI();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to pass your panel to the `JScrollPane` constructor:

```
    public static void makeGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final Exam Scheduler");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final Test add = new Test();
        add.addComponents(panel);

        final JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel,  // <-- here
             JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

        add.printToGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```